# Importing and debugging a Python Django project made in a different environment

Tags: python, django, windows, virtualenv

I am working on a Django project that was created by another developer on a different machine. I see that in the root of the application, there is a .virtualenv directory. Is it possible to simply setup this project locally on my Windows machine using the project settings and Python version (the app uses 2.7), so that I can run it like a local Django application so debugging is feasible?

I have access to the development web server and have copied the full source of the app down to my Win7 machine but cannot seem to get things setup correctly to run the app locally so I can debug.

I currently have Python 2.7, 2.7.5 and 3.3.2 installed on my local dev machine. I would call myself pretty new to Django and Virtualenv.

If anyone has any guidance on how I can get my environment straitened out so I can run the app with debugging, I would be very thankful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using a virtualenv environment created on a different machine is not recommended. There are things hard-wired for the particular system it was created on, and some apps may have components compiled for that particular system.

You should [create a new virtualenv environment](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#installation) on your machine, install dependencies and move the Django project there.

Note on installing dependencies - there might be a file named `requirements.txt` somewhere. If it's there and it's kept up to date you can install all the dependencies by running a single command while in your virtualenv:

```
pip -r requirements.txt install
```

If you can't find it ask the other developer to create it. He just need to do this inside his own environment:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I once faced the same problem and it took me so much time to configure another environment that I eventually had to create a VM with the same version of OS and libraries. I then made a raw copy of the project and it worked fine.